# Spatial Database - Too many spatial objects to display

Tags: sql-server, spatial

I'm playing with SQL Server spatial database and managed to draw something using ellipses (and hyper and hypo-ellipses).

But I'm getting this error:

> "Too many spatial objects to display - displaying the first 5000 objects. Please refine your query."

Most of my graphic is being displayed. Removing a couple of ellipses "solves" the problem.

Can I change that limit to allow me to draw more objects?

Below is my example query:

```
DECLARE @plano AS TABLE (t FLOAT, x float, y FLOAT)
DECLARE @t FLOAT = -3.14, @f FLOAT = .3,
        @mx FLOAT = 8, @my FLOAT = 10

WHILE @t < 3.14
BEGIN
    SET @t = @t + 0.01

    INSERT INTO @plano
        SELECT @t, @mx*power(abs(SIN(@t)),@f), @my*power(abs(COS(@t)),@f)
        UNION
        SELECT @t, -@mx*power(abs(SIN(@t)),@f), @my*power(abs(COS(@t)),@f)
        UNION
        SELECT @t,  @mx*SIN(@t),(@my/10)*COS(@t)
        UNION
        SELECT @t, -@mx*power(SIN(@t),5),-@my*power(abs(COS(@t)),5)
        UNION
        SELECT @t, 3*COS(@t)*COS( 0.3) - 4*SIN(@t)*SIN( 0.3)+ 4, 3*COS(@t)*SIN( 0.3)+ 4*SIN(@t)*COS( 0.3) + 5
        UNION
        SELECT @t, 3*COS(@t)*COS(-0.3) - 4*SIN(@t)*SIN(-0.3)- 4, 3*COS(@t)*SIN(-0.3)+ 4*SIN(@t)*COS(-0.3) + 5
        UNION
        SELECT @t, 1.5*SIN(@t) + 3, 2*COS(@t) + 5
        UNION
        SELECT @t, 1.5*SIN(@t) - 3, 2*COS(@t) + 5
END

SELECT
    t,x, y,
    geometry::Point(x, y, 0).STBuffer(0.1)
FROM
    @plano
```

Comment: That's a limitation of the SSMS spatial results tab.

Comment: SSMS isn't a presentation tool, it's a management tool. Your presentation layer will be able to handle far more than 5,000 elements, I'm sure.

Comment: Can you use STUnionAggregate to make one multipolygon?